# Same conditions in WHERE clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is from https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/01/46-questions-on-sql-to-test-a-data-science-professional-skilltest-solution/

Can someone explain a little more to this?

Why does the order of WHERE clause matter?

Q6) Which of the following query will find all the unique students who have taken more than one course?

A. `SELECT DISTINCT e1.sid FROM enrolled AS e1, enrolled AS e2 WHERE e1.sid != e2.sid AND e1.cid != e2.cid`

B. `SELECT DISTINCT e1.sid FROM enrolled AS e1, enrolled AS e2 WHERE e1.sid = e2.sid AND e1.cid = e2.cid`

C. `SELECT DISTINCT e1.sid FROM enrolled AS e1, enrolled AS e2 WHERE e1.sid != e2.sid AND e1.cid != e2.cid`

D. `SELECT DISTINCT e1.sid FROM enrolled AS e1, enrolled AS e2 WHERE e1.sid = e2.sid AND e1.cid != e2.cid`

Solution: D

Option D would be a right option. This query will first apply self join on enrolled table and then it evaluate the condition e1.sid = e2.sid AND e1.cid != e2.cid.

Comment: A question that uses archaic `JOIN` syntax is indicative of a lot of other issues.

Comment: re "Why does the order of WHERE clause matter?" there is no difference in order, the differences are whether the operators are equals or not equals

Comment: The syntax in this material is outdated (from the 80s). I suggest you get newer course.

Comment: I can't see a difference between A.) and C.). Possibly in C.) the last operator should be a `=`?